# Moving image to another folder

Tags: ruby

currently reading Learn To Program. Im at page 91-92 where you create a program that moves images from your USB drive to desired location and changing the name of each image. But i get the follwing error when runing the program. Using Ubuntu as you can tell, but get **"Invalid cross-device link"**. Any ideas of how to solve this?

```
pierre@ubuntu:~/ruby$ ruby move.rb
What would you like to call this batch?
IMG

Downloading 1 files: .move.rb:36:in `rename': Invalid cross-device link - (/media/SanDisk Cruzer Blade/pictures/UMG.jpg, IMG01.jpg) (Errno::EXDEV)
    from move.rb:36:in `block in <main>'
    from move.rb:17:in `each'
    from move.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

This is the code

```
# Heres where the pictures are stored
Dir.chdir '/home/pierre/Skrivbord'

# First we find all of the pictures to be moved
pic_names = Dir['/media/SanDisk Cruzer Blade/pictures/**/*.{JPG,jpg}']

puts 'What would you like to call this batch?'
batch_name = gets.chomp

puts
print "Downloading #{pic_names.length} files: "

# This will be our counter. We'll start at 1 today,
# though normally I like to count from 0.
pic_number = 1

pic_names.each do |name|
  print '.' # This is our "progress bar".

  new_name = if pic_number < 10
    "#{batch_name}0#{pic_number}.jpg"
  else
    "#{batch_name}#{pic_number}.jpg"
  end

# This renames the picture, but since "name" has a big long
# path on it, and "new_name" doesn't, it also moves the file to the current
# working directory, which is now Katy's PictureInbox folder. Since it's a
# *move*, this effectively downloads and deletes the originals. And since this 
# is a memory card, not a hard drive, each of these takes a second or so; hence,
# the little dots let her know that my program didn't hose her machine.
# (Some marriage advice from your favourite author/programmer: it's all about 
# the little things.)

# Now where were we? Oh, yeah...
  File.rename name, new_name
    # Finally, we increment the counter.
  pic_number = pic_number + 1
end

puts # This is so we aren't on progress bar line.
puts 'Done, cutie!'
```

Comment: Pierre, I guess you can't rename a file if it's not on the same file system. You would have to move the file, not rename - using FileUtils.

Answer (score 2):

> .. you are trying to use "rename" to physically move a  file, and the system is objecting
>   to this misconception. File.rename can only rename files, it cannot
>   move them. It works only on one storage device/volume/whatever.

```
require 'fileutils'
include FileUtils
cp(old, new )
rm (old)
```

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/78627

Comment: [FileUtils::mv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-i-mv) would be more appropriate here.